# How to provide a secure authorization with ajax?

Tags: javascript, authentication

The backend team provided me a POST call to create a new user account similar to the one in the snippet with an encrypted Authorization string in the header. How can the service be protected from violations, e.g. somebody could write a script and run it as a loop in the Chrome Browser console to call the service. The Authorization string is hardcoded in the frontend and requests a bearer token to create the account in a second server call. What would be a safer approach?

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'New Account',
    body: 'Create account for new user',
    userId: 1
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      Authorization: `B dGhN4787496087493c87nR67faaf1dGS3g=`,
      AuthorizationHash: `B e9267f8a4709171e849e54aaf1db7319c`,    
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log)
```

Comment: If someone is authorized, then they are authorized. If you don't trust them, don't authorize them.

Comment: @Quentin How can I prevent a console attack? What service design is needed?

Comment: An attacker can always use a REST client as an attacking application.  At which point the browser isn't even involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend is fundamentally insecure and there's nothing you can do about it. It's up to the backend team to protect their endpoints from attacks by implementing techniques such as:

- Only allowing logged-in users to do things
- Rate limiting
- CSRF tokens

By the way, I'm assuming you're talking about protecting against rapidly calling the endpoint.